# Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog does not work for Windows 10 IoT

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10, messagedialog, windows-10-iot-core

```
            await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Test").ShowAsync();
```

Has anyone else noticed this?  Is there an easy work around ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the some problem and I did't found any trick. I made myself a MessageDialog with a  and  It's not so hard to build it. Try do take a look this http://bitaware.altervista.org/messagedialog-for-iot/
The unique problem is that it do not work across platforms. If you would this behavior you have to get a condition

```
string platform = AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily;
if (platform == "Windows.IoT")
{ 
    //Your code for IoT
}
else
{
    //Your code for other devices
}
```

I know is not elegant but I think we have no other choice.
I hope it was helpful